# pandas Series elementwise boolean checks are ambigious

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure how to use .bool(), any, all, or empty, to make the two different examples work.  Each throws me the Ambiguous Value error

```
import pandas as pd


first = pd.Series([1,0,0])
second = pd.Series([1,2,1])

number_df = pd.DataFrame( {'first': first,  'second': second} )

bool_df = pd.DataFrame( {'testA': pd.Series([True, False, True]), 'testB': pd.Series([True, False, False])})

#ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). 

""" both the next two lines fail with the ambiguous Series issue"""
#each row should be true or false 
bool_df['double_zero_check'] = (number_df['first'] != 0) and (number_df['second'] != 0 )
bool_df['parity'] = bool_df['testA'] and bool_df['testB']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the bitwise and (`&`) to compare Series elementwise - more in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
In [3]: bool_df['double_zero_check'] = (number_df['first'] != 0) & (number_df['second'] != 0 )

In [4]: bool_df['parity'] = bool_df['testA'] & bool_df['testB']

In [5]: bool_df
Out[5]: 
   testA  testB double_zero_check parity
0   True   True              True   True
1  False  False             False  False
2   True  False             False  False
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the bitwise and (&) operator. `and` works for boolean not for Pandas Series.

```
bool_df['double_zero_check'] = (number_df['first'] != 0) & (number_df['second'] != 0 )
bool_df['parity'] = bool_df['testA'] & bool_df['testB']
```